# Can't get 'bert' model to run using ktrain and pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror, bert-language-model, ktrain

I try to work with ktrain to finetune bert model. I'm using pandas dataframe named train_df to store my data.

`x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(train_df['text'], train_df['target'], shuffle=True, test_size = 0.2, random_state=random_seed, stratify=train_df['target'])`

I'm using function texts_from_array because I'm reading the data with pandas dataframe
When I want to Convert data to features for BERT I get ValueError (ValueError: x_train must be a list or NumPy array).

```
(x_train_bert,  y_train_bert), (x_val_bert, y_val_bert), preproc = text.texts_from_array(x_train=x_train, y_train=y_train,                                                                                         x_test = x_val, y_test=y_val,
                                                                                          class_names= ["0", "1"],
                                                                                          preprocess_mode='bert',
                                                                                          lang = 'en',
                                                                                          maxlen=65,
                                                                                          max_features=35000)
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution and now it is working correctly.

```
(x_train_bert, y_train_bert), (x_val_bert, y_val_bert), preproc = text.texts_from_array(x_train=x_train.tolist(), y_train=y_train.tolist(), x_test = x_val.tolist(), y_test=y_val.tolist(),class_names= ["0", "1"],preprocess_mode='bert',lang = 'en', maxlen=65, max_features=35000)
```